# PHP object composition practice

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a Parent Class Model Like this:

```
namespace vendor\appname\core;

class Model
{
    protected $db;
    protected $session;
    protected $cookie;
    protected $record;

    public function __construct()  
    {
        $this->db = new Db;
        $this->session = new Session;
        $this->cookie  = new Cookie;
        $this->record  = new Record;
    }
}
```

here I have my child models where i can extend the base model and use there objects

```
namespace vendor\appname\models;

use vendor\appname\core;  

class Login extends Model
{
      // here i can use simply like so 
      $this->db->prepare() // and so on 
      $this->session->set() // and so on so fourth
}
```

So if i have 100 class should i do the same thing "object composition " is this a good practice ??? what about the registry pattern or factory ? is it possible to implement it here ? or dependency injection

Comment: You should be using dependency injection.

Comment: @JonStirling what i know about dependency injection that u type hint the class name and then u pass the object but in my case how can i do it ? im extending the parent class !!

Comment: You're example do not show object composition, it shows inheritance. Instead of asking if you can use some given DP, you should clarify your question and explain what you need to do.

Comment: @Kwadz object composition on the Model

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, i think you should probably read and research more about the first five OO design principle (SOLID) and General Responsibility Assignment Software Principle (GRASP) to understand more about design pattern and object creation.
Having said that, what you are doing is more of inheritance instead of composition. To make it simple,

**Inheritance** is more of an "is-a" relationship, for example a UserModel "is-a" Model, thus all properties and methods of a Model will be part of a UserModel.

**Aggregation** is more like "uses-a" relationship. A Model "uses-a" QueryBuilder and DatabaseClient.

**Composition** on the other hand, is more like "has-a" or "contain-a" relationship for instance, Book "contain-a" Page.

This is just an example in hope of making things a bit clear for you. Having understanding in these and also Solid and Grasp would make you understand about various design patterns available.